# Building a dependency tree

Tags: python, graph, tree, dependencies, constraints

I have N-nodes and want to build a dependency pairs-graph given weight matrix by maximizing the sum:

```
 [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9]
```

Positioned along a line.

Then I have a matrix of connection weights.
This matrix is symmetric i.e. the nodes potential connections are not directed,
F.e. :

```
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [34, 96,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [39, 30, 33,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [50, 22, 53, 36,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [63, 89, 26, 93, 42,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [56, 89, 46, 44, 72, 34,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [22, 66, 15, 89, 72, 86, 60,  0,  0,  0],
   [23, 62, 99, 39, 92, 24, 55,  6,  0,  0],
   [43,  1, 32, 84, 27, 38, 84, 14,  6,  0]
```

(or u can mirror to fill the zeros, if the algorithm requires it)

I need to connect all nodes in pairs such that the SUM of the weights is MAXIMUM.

There is ONE condition:

> **the connections can not cross each other** i.e. if there is pair (n,n+x) you **cant** have pair (m,p) where m > n and m < n+x and (p < n or p > n+x) i.e. a pair cant start/end inside another pair and at the same time end/start outside of it

F.e. :  1 <--> 3 and 2 <--> 4 is not allowed

but  :  1 <--> 3 and 1 <--> 4 is OK i.e. a node can participate in multiple pairs

---

I'm thinking of [Constraint programming](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_example), but does not seem to fit the pattern !

Any ideas ?

---

Visual example .. in my case directions dont matter, but if the algorithm is easier that is Ok too.

[image: dep]

Comment: in your example why "is" and "a" are not linked? What is the stopping criteria? Once all items are covered by any pair, stop?

Comment: yes once all covered stop ... i have some progress here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176005/constraint-optimization-using-arbitrary-functions

Comment: In your example, if I remove the arrow from "sentence" to "is" it will still be covered. by arrows. Every word is inside a pair. Why then this arrow is there and there is no arrow between "is" and "a"? Adding an arrow between "is" and "a" would certainly increase the sum based on your matrix. And make algorithm so much easier

Comment: I could also add an arrow from "sentence" to "This" and increase the sum even further

Comment: It looks to me like a classical dynamic programming problem

Comment: ... but this is one of many valid cfgs.. the one with max sum is selected...

Comment: It is not max sum if I can add arrows to this cfg and it is still valid and the sum is higher

Comment: there has to be connection to every word.. but they cant intersect

Comment: "Every word is inside a pair", not inside a pair, but connected

Comment: a word can be connected with multiple words, but u dont connect already connected words

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but here you have that connections don't cross each other and every word is connected (maybe multiple times but this is not against the rules).

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional, List, Tuple
import functools


weight_matrix = np.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [34, 96,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [39, 30, 33,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [50, 22, 53, 36,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [63, 89, 26, 93, 42,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [56, 89, 46, 44, 72, 34,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [22, 66, 15, 89, 72, 86, 60,  0,  0,  0],
   [23, 62, 99, 39, 92, 24, 55,  6,  0,  0],
   [43,  1, 32, 84, 27, 38, 84, 14,  6,  0]])

@functools.cache
def find_max_pairs(
    first_node:int, 
    last_node:int) -> Tuple[List[Tuple[int, int]], int]:
    max_ = float('-inf')
    res = None
    if last_node == first_node + 1:
        return [(first_node, last_node, )], weight_matrix[last_node, first_node]
    for splitter in range(first_node + 1, last_node):
        left_pairs, left_max = find_max_pairs(first_node, splitter)
        right_pairs, right_max = find_max_pairs(splitter, last_node)
        if left_max + right_max > max_:
            max_ = left_max + right_max
            res = (left_pairs, right_pairs)
    return [(first_node, last_node, )] + res[0] + res[1], max_ + weight_matrix[last_node, first_node]
    

find_max_pairs(0, weight_matrix.shape[0] - 1)
```

Output:

```
([(0, 9),
  (0, 6),
  (0, 1),
  (1, 6),
  (1, 5),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (3, 5),
  (3, 4),
  (4, 5),
  (5, 6),
  (6, 9),
  (6, 8),
  (6, 7),
  (7, 8),
  (8, 9)],
 875)
​
```

Comment: thanks..will try to understand it...a word can be connected with multiple words, but u dont connect when both are already connected  –

Comment: I don't think I can fully understand this criteria from your example. It seems like the result depends on the way you implement it. In your example I could connect only [("This", "is"), ("a", "sentence")] then I have to stop based on what you said. Or I could first connect [("This", "sentence") then ("This", "is"), ("is", "sentence"), ("a", "sentence")]. It is valid and I certainly beat your max because I have and additional connection

Comment: i see.. u are correct this is artifact,, because i'm still using random numbers in the matrix.. once i use real numbers it should be more correct ,, thats the idea :). But for this i need to parse GBs of text. .thats the second part

Comment: in current case u stop at [("This", "is"), ("a", "sentence")] .. that is valid answer for the stats u have .. the idea is the more stats u collect the more correct dep-tree u get i.e. the numbers in the mx will be such that the digram in the pic will have higher combined score

Comment: But the problem that it depends on how I pass the tree. The correct answer should be  [("This", "sentence"), ("This", "is"), ("is", "sentence"), ("a", "sentence")] as it gives the maximum weight sum, imo

Comment: if thats the parse order (is, sentence) is invalid because those two words were already connected